# Spring Boot Stomp WebSocket

Tags: spring-boot, stomp, spring-websocket, java-websocket, embedded-tomcat-8

I seem to be running into an issue bumping up against the 8k size limit that embedded tomcat has for stomp websocket messages.

When sending a message from server to client I am getting the following error. Based on the documentation I've read, it seems that tomcat has a limit of 8k for messages going across websockets, but ive also read that Stomp can send partial messages and have the client reassemble them which doesnt seem to be happening.

The message is never getting to the client side handler so I'm pretty confident the issue is in my WebSocketConfig but it seems no matter what parameter I've tried I can not get over the A) size limit of 8k messages and/or B) if its over the buffer limit, send it in partial message chunks.

Both sides have the following error code

```
[code=1009, reason=The decoded text message was too big for the output buffer and the endpoint does not support partial messages]
```

I pretty sure I'm missing something easy but can't seem to put my finger on it. Any extra eyes would be appreciated. Thanks!

Server Side Stomp WebSocket Config

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {


private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebSocketConfig.class);



@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
    config.enableSimpleBroker(
            "/resp",
            "/not", 
            "/sub"
        );
    config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/admin");
    config.setUserDestinationPrefix("/admin");

}


@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    RequestUpgradeStrategy upgradeStrategy = new TomcatRequestUpgradeStrategy();
    registry.addEndpoint("/cmd",
                        "/connect")
                        .setHandshakeHandler(new DefaultHandshakeHandler(upgradeStrategy))
                        .setAllowedOrigins("*")
                        .withSockJS();




}

@Override
public boolean configureMessageConverters(List<MessageConverter> messageConverters) {
    messageConverters.add(new org.springframework.messaging.converter.StringMessageConverter());
    return true;
}


@Override
public void configureWebSocketTransport(WebSocketTransportRegistration registration) {
    registration.setSendTimeLimit(15*1000);
    registration.setMessageSizeLimit(16*1024);
    registration.setSendBufferSizeLimit(16*1024);


}

@Bean
public ServletServerContainerFactoryBean createServletServerContainerFactoryBean() {
    ServletServerContainerFactoryBean container = new ServletServerContainerFactoryBean();

    container.setMaxTextMessageBufferSize(16*1024);
    container.setMaxBinaryMessageBufferSize(16*1024);
    logger.info("Websocket factory returned");
    ContainerProvider.getWebSocketContainer().setDefaultMaxTextMessageBufferSize(20*1024);
    return container;
}

}
```

Server Side Trace Messages

```
2016-01-27 18:20:54.342 DEBUG 3358 --- [clientInboundChannel-13] o.s.m.s.b.SimpleBrokerMessageHandler     : Processing MESSAGE destination=/sub/user-user5e1cc9e1c97a450180ed6ad41d575a33 session=5e1cc9e1c97a450180ed6ad41d575a33 user=core payload={"headers":{"deviceSessionId":"67669nys","message-id":"bf8Pcpx"},"payload":"{\"t...(truncated)
2016-01-27 18:20:54.342 DEBUG 3358 --- [clientInboundChannel-13] o.s.m.s.b.SimpleBrokerMessageHandler     : Broadcasting to 1 sessions.
2016-01-27 18:20:54.342  INFO 3358 --- [clientInboundChannel-13] c.l.a.c.AdminProfileController           : Response sent: /channelList
2016-01-27 18:20:54.342 TRACE 3358 --- [clientInboundChannel-13] o.s.m.h.i.InvocableHandlerMethod         : Method [processObject] returned [null]
2016-01-27 18:20:54.342 TRACE 3358 --- [clientOutboundChannel-3] o.s.messaging.simp.stomp.StompEncoder    : Encoding STOMP MESSAGE, headers={apiVersion=[5], message-id=[bf8Pcpx], destination=[/admin/sub/user], content-type=[text/plain;charset=UTF-8], subscription=[0]}
2016-01-27 18:20:54.343 TRACE 3358 --- [clientOutboundChannel-3] s.w.s.s.t.s.WebSocketServerSockJsSession : Cancelling heartbeat in session 5e1cc9e1c97a450180ed6ad41d575a33
2016-01-27 18:20:54.346 TRACE 3358 --- [clientOutboundChannel-3] s.w.s.s.t.s.WebSocketServerSockJsSession : Preparing to write SockJsFrame content='a["MESSAGE\napiVersion:5\nmessage-id:bf8Pcpx\ndestination:/admin/sub/user\nconte...(truncated)'
2016-01-27 18:20:54.347 TRACE 3358 --- [clientOutboundChannel-3] s.w.s.s.t.s.WebSocketServerSockJsSession : Writing SockJsFrame content='a["MESSAGE\napiVersion:5\nmessage-id:bf8Pcpx\ndestination:/admin/sub/user\nconte...(truncated)'
2016-01-27 18:20:54.347 TRACE 3358 --- [clientOutboundChannel-3] o.s.w.s.adapter.NativeWebSocketSession   : Sending TextMessage payload=[a["MESSAGE..], byteCount=20097, last=true], StandardWebSocketSession[id=0, uri=/admin/connect/401/5e1cc9e1c97a450180ed6ad41d575a33/websocket]
2016-01-27 18:20:54.373 TRACE 3358 --- [clientOutboundChannel-3] s.w.s.s.t.s.WebSocketServerSockJsSession : Scheduled heartbeat in session 5e1cc9e1c97a450180ed6ad41d575a33
2016-01-27 18:20:54.373 TRACE 3358 --- [http-nio-8084-exec-6] s.w.s.s.t.s.WebSocketServerSockJsSession : Cancelling heartbeat in session 5e1cc9e1c97a450180ed6ad41d575a33
2016-01-27 18:20:54.373 DEBUG 3358 --- [http-nio-8084-exec-6] s.w.s.h.LoggingWebSocketHandlerDecorator : WebSocketServerSockJsSession[id=5e1cc9e1c97a450180ed6ad41d575a33] closed with CloseStatus[code=1009, reason=The decoded text message was too big for the output buffer and the endpoint does not support partial messages]
2016-01-27 18:20:54.373 DEBUG 3358 --- [http-nio-8084-exec-6] o.s.w.s.m.SubProtocolWebSocketHandler    : Clearing session 5e1cc9e1c97a450180ed6ad41d575a33
2016-01-27 18:20:54.374 TRACE 3358 --- [http-nio-8084-exec-6] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Publishing event in org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@648c94da: SessionDisconnectEvent[sessionId=5e1cc9e1c97a450180ed6ad41d575a33, CloseStatus[code=1009, reason=The decoded text message was too big for the output buffer and the endpoint does not support partial messages]]
 2016-01-27 18:20:54.374 DEBUG 3358 --- [http-nio-8084-exec-6] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean
```

Client Side Error Stack

```
2016-01-28 09:33:14.342 ERROR 810 --- [lient-AsyncIO-1] o.s.w.s.s.c.WebSocketClientSockJsSession : Transport error in WebSocketClientSockJsSession[id='c5c680b9a75e488ba7bb129f90b700e6, url=ws://localhost:8084/admin/connect]

java.io.IOException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException: Unable to write the complete message as the WebSocket connection has been closed
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.startMessageBlock(WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.java:282) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsSession.sendCloseMessage(WsSession.java:584) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsSession.doClose(WsSession.java:488) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsSession.close(WsSession.java:455) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameClient.close(WsFrameClient.java:94) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameClient.access$100(WsFrameClient.java:31) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameClient$WsFrameClientCompletionHandler.completed(WsFrameClient.java:134) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameClient$WsFrameClientCompletionHandler.completed(WsFrameClient.java:108) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at sun.nio.ch.Invoker.invokeUnchecked(Invoker.java:126) [na:1.8.0_45]
at sun.nio.ch.Invoker.invokeDirect(Invoker.java:157) [na:1.8.0_45]
at sun.nio.ch.UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.implRead(UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:553) [na:1.8.0_45]
at sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.read(AsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:276) [na:1.8.0_45]
at sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.read(AsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:297) [na:1.8.0_45]
at java.nio.channels.AsynchronousSocketChannel.read(AsynchronousSocketChannel.java:420) [na:1.8.0_45]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.AsyncChannelWrapperNonSecure.read(AsyncChannelWrapperNonSecure.java:52) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameClient.processSocketRead(WsFrameClient.java:79) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameClient.access$300(WsFrameClient.java:31) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameClient$WsFrameClientCompletionHandler.completed(WsFrameClient.java:125) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameClient$WsFrameClientCompletionHandler.completed(WsFrameClient.java:108) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at sun.nio.ch.Invoker.invokeUnchecked(Invoker.java:126) [na:1.8.0_45]
at sun.nio.ch.Invoker$2.run(Invoker.java:218) [na:1.8.0_45]
at sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl$1.run(AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl.java:112) [na:1.8.0_45]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_45]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_45]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_45]
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException: Unable to write the complete message as the WebSocket connection has been closed
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.FutureToSendHandler.get(FutureToSendHandler.java:102) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.startMessageBlock(WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.java:275) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to write the complete message as the WebSocket connection has been closed
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsSession.registerFuture(WsSession.java:658) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.FutureToSendHandler.get(FutureToSendHandler.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
... 25 common frames omitted

2016-01-28 09:33:14.343  WARN 810 --- [lient-AsyncIO-1] l.e.c.w.CustomDefaultStompSessionHandler : handleTransportError

java.io.IOException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException: Unable to write the complete message as the WebSocket connection has been closed
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.startMessageBlock(WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.java:282) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsSession.sendCloseMessage(WsSession.java:584) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsSession.doClose(WsSession.java:488) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsSession.close(WsSession.java:455) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameClient.close(WsFrameClient.java:94) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameClient.access$100(WsFrameClient.java:31) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameClient$WsFrameClientCompletionHandler.completed(WsFrameClient.java:134) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameClient$WsFrameClientCompletionHandler.completed(WsFrameClient.java:108) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at sun.nio.ch.Invoker.invokeUnchecked(Invoker.java:126) [na:1.8.0_45]
at sun.nio.ch.Invoker.invokeDirect(Invoker.java:157) [na:1.8.0_45]
at sun.nio.ch.UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.implRead(UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:553) [na:1.8.0_45]
at sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.read(AsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:276) [na:1.8.0_45]
at sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.read(AsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:297) [na:1.8.0_45]
at java.nio.channels.AsynchronousSocketChannel.read(AsynchronousSocketChannel.java:420) [na:1.8.0_45]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.AsyncChannelWrapperNonSecure.read(AsyncChannelWrapperNonSecure.java:52) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameClient.processSocketRead(WsFrameClient.java:79) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameClient.access$300(WsFrameClient.java:31) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameClient$WsFrameClientCompletionHandler.completed(WsFrameClient.java:125) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameClient$WsFrameClientCompletionHandler.completed(WsFrameClient.java:108) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at sun.nio.ch.Invoker.invokeUnchecked(Invoker.java:126) [na:1.8.0_45]
at sun.nio.ch.Invoker$2.run(Invoker.java:218) [na:1.8.0_45]
at sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl$1.run(AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl.java:112) [na:1.8.0_45]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_45]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_45]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_45]
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException: Unable to write the complete message as the WebSocket connection has been closed
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.FutureToSendHandler.get(FutureToSendHandler.java:102) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.startMessageBlock(WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.java:275) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to write the complete message as the WebSocket connection has been closed
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsSession.registerFuture(WsSession.java:658) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.FutureToSendHandler.get(FutureToSendHandler.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
... 25 common frames omitted

java.io.IOException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException: Unable to write the complete message as the WebSocket connection has been closed
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.startMessageBlock(WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.java:282)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsSession.sendCloseMessage(WsSession.java:584)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsSession.doClose(WsSession.java:488)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsSession.close(WsSession.java:455)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameClient.close(WsFrameClient.java:94)
**2016-01-28 09:33:14.345 DEBUG 810 --- [lient-AsyncIO-1] o.s.w.s.s.c.WebSocketClientSockJsSession : Transport closed with CloseStatus[code=1009, reason=The decoded text message was too big for the output buffer and the endpoint does not support partial messages] in WebSocketClientSockJsSession[id='c5c680b9a75e488ba7bb129f90b700e6, url=ws://localhost.local:8084/admin/connect]**
2016-01-28 09:33:14.345 DEBUG 810 --- [lient-AsyncIO-1] o.s.m.simp.stomp.DefaultStompSession     : Connection closed session id=31d8ea85-ff24-ce54-c7cc-72352b88b493
2016-01-28 09:33:14.345  WARN 810 --- [lient-AsyncIO-1] l.e.c.w.CustomDefaultStompSessionHandler : Server disconnect
null
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameClient.access$100(WsFrameClient.java:31)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameClient$WsFrameClientCompletionHandler.completed(WsFrameClient.java:134)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameClient$WsFrameClientCompletionHandler.completed(WsFrameClient.java:108)
at sun.nio.ch.Invoker.invokeUnchecked(Invoker.java:126)
at sun.nio.ch.Invoker.invokeDirect(Invoker.java:157)
at sun.nio.ch.UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.implRead(UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:553)
at sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.read(AsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:276)
at sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.read(AsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:297)
at java.nio.channels.AsynchronousSocketChannel.read(AsynchronousSocketChannel.java:420)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.AsyncChannelWrapperNonSecure.read(AsyncChannelWrapperNonSecure.java:52)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameClient.processSocketRead(WsFrameClient.java:79)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameClient.access$300(WsFrameClient.java:31)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameClient$WsFrameClientCompletionHandler.completed(WsFrameClient.java:125)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameClient$WsFrameClientCompletionHandler.completed(WsFrameClient.java:108)
at sun.nio.ch.Invoker.invokeUnchecked(Invoker.java:126)
at sun.nio.ch.Invoker$2.run(Invoker.java:218)
at sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl$1.run(AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl.java:112)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException: Unable to write the complete message as the WebSocket connection has been closed
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.FutureToSendHandler.get(FutureToSendHandler.java:102)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.startMessageBlock(WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.java:275)
... 24 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to write the complete message as the WebSocket connection has been closed
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsSession.registerFuture(WsSession.java:658)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.FutureToSendHandler.get(FutureToSendHandler.java:92)
... 25 more
org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.ConnectionLostException: Connection closed
at org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.DefaultStompSession.afterConnectionClosed(DefaultStompSession.java:459)
at org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.WebSocketStompClient$WebSocketTcpConnectionHandlerAdapter.afterConnectionClosed(WebSocketStompClient.java:353)
at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.client.AbstractClientSockJsSession.afterTransportClosed(AbstractClientSockJsSession.java:321)
at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.client.WebSocketTransport$ClientSockJsWebSocketHandler.afterConnectionClosed(WebSocketTransport.java:172)
at org.springframework.web.socket.adapter.standard.StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter.onClose(StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter.java:141)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsSession.fireEndpointOnClose(WsSession.java:538)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsSession.doClose(WsSession.java:489)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsSession.close(WsSession.java:455)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameClient.close(WsFrameClient.java:94)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameClient.access$100(WsFrameClient.java:31)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameClient$WsFrameClientCompletionHandler.completed(WsFrameClient.java:134)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameClient$WsFrameClientCompletionHandler.completed(WsFrameClient.java:108)
at sun.nio.ch.Invoker.invokeUnchecked(Invoker.java:126)
at sun.nio.ch.Invoker.invokeDirect(Invoker.java:157)
at sun.nio.ch.UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.implRead(UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:553)
at sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.read(AsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:276)
at sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.read(AsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:297)
at java.nio.channels.AsynchronousSocketChannel.read(AsynchronousSocketChannel.java:420)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.AsyncChannelWrapperNonSecure.read(AsyncChannelWrapperNonSecure.java:52)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameClient.processSocketRead(WsFrameClient.java:79)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameClient.access$300(WsFrameClient.java:31)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameClient$WsFrameClientCompletionHandler.completed(WsFrameClient.java:125)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameClient$WsFrameClientCompletionHandler.completed(WsFrameClient.java:108)
at sun.nio.ch.Invoker.invokeUnchecked(Invoker.java:126)
at sun.nio.ch.Invoker$2.run(Invoker.java:218)
at sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl$1.run(AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl.java:112)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2016-01-28 09:33:14.346 DEBUG 810 --- [lient-AsyncIO-1] o.s.w.s.s.c.WebSocketClientSockJsSession : Closing session with CloseStatus[code=1000, reason=null] in WebSocketClientSockJsSession[id='c5c680b9a75e488ba7bb129f90b700e6, url=ws://localhost.local:8084/admin/connect]
2016-01-28 09:33:14.346 DEBUG 810 --- [lient-AsyncIO-1] o.s.w.s.s.c.WebSocketClientSockJsSession : Ignoring close (already closing or closed), current state=CLOSED
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After banging my head against the wall for a week, I discovered the problem. The client I was using (internal spring java websocket stomp client) is not capable of partial messaging nor is it configurable with the size of buffer for messages. The answer(workaround) was to take the internal java stop client code and implement my own version of it that had a configurable message buffer size as well as implement a way to handle partial messages. Hope this anyone else who hits this problem.

Comment: Hello @jediknight562 !  I appreciate if you could share your code on this! Can you please send it to askar.ibragimov@gmail.com or share via guthub?

Answer (score 5):

You can change max text buffer size according to your needs:

```
WebSocketContainer container = ContainerProvider.getWebSocketContainer();
container.setDefaultMaxTextMessageBufferSize(MAX_TEXT_MESSAGE_BUFFER_SIZE);
WebSocketClient wsClient = new StandardWebSocketClient(container);
```