# Websocket java client Spring + Stomp: Transport error: ConnectionLostException

Tags: spring, websocket, stomp, sockjs, java-client

I'm trying to create an standalone Java app as a websocket client using for this Spring with Stomp and Sockjs, taking in consideration the spring specifications and the spring-portafolio examples and I'm getting this error:

```
15:18:01.342 [main] DEBUG com.example.client.WebSocketClientTest - Connecting to : ws://localhost:8080/socket/hello
15:18:01.541 [WebSocketClient-AsyncIO-1] ERROR com.example.client.MyStompSessionHandler - Transport error
org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.ConnectionLostException: Connection closed
at org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.DefaultStompSession.afterConnectionClosed(DefaultStompSession.java:483) [spring-messaging-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.WebSocketStompClient$WebSocketTcpConnectionHandlerAdapter.afterConnectionClosed(WebSocketStompClient.java:354) [spring-websocket-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.client.AbstractClientSockJsSession.afterTransportClosed(AbstractClientSockJsSession.java:321) [spring-websocket-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.client.WebSocketTransport$ClientSockJsWebSocketHandler.afterConnectionClosed(WebSocketTransport.java:172) [spring-websocket-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.socket.adapter.standard.StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter.onClose(StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter.java:141) [spring-websocket-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]...
```

My code in the java client side is:

```
StandardWebSocketClient webSocketClient = new StandardWebSocketClient();
List<Transport> transports = new ArrayList<>();
transports.add(new WebSocketTransport(webSocketClient));
SockJsClient sockJsClient = new SockJsClient(transports);
ThreadPoolTaskScheduler taskScheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
taskScheduler.afterPropertiesSet();
String stompUrl = "ws://localhost:8080/socket/hello";
WebSocketStompClient stompClient = new WebSocketStompClient(sockJsClient);
stompClient.setMessageConverter(new StringMessageConverter());
stompClient.setTaskScheduler(taskScheduler);
stompClient.setDefaultHeartbeat(new long[] {0, 0});

StompSessionHandler sessionHandler = new MyStompSessionHandler();
stompClient.connect(stompUrl, sessionHandler);
stompClient.setTaskScheduler(taskScheduler);
```

And the server side was made using Spring MVC with Stomp and SockJs, the server works perfectly with a javascript client, this is the config that I used:

```
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
    config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
    config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
}
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/hello")
            .setHandshakeHandler(new DefaultHandshakeHandler(new TomcatRequestUpgradeStrategy()))
            .withSockJS();
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Can anyone give me an idea of how to fix it or how to create a Java client to connect with an spring websocket server?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem. Cause was recieving too big message which default STOMP Spring/Tomcat WS client cannot handle because *it is not capable of partial messaging*. [This StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36457020/5148407) worked for me (I have set `MAX_TEXT_MESSAGE_BUFFER_SIZE=20*1024*1024`):

```
WebSocketContainer container = ContainerProvider.getWebSocketContainer();
container.setDefaultMaxTextMessageBufferSize(MAX_TEXT_MESSAGE_BUFFER_SIZE);
WebSocketClient wsClient = new StandardWebSocketClient(container);
```

Setting inboundMessageSizeLimit had no effect:

```
WebSocketStompClient stompClient = new WebSocketStompClient(sockJsClient);
stompClient.setInboundMessageSizeLimit(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

Comment: Changed the buffer size. Even then, the issue persists. Is this an open bug - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/19539? Frankly, I'm stuck.